# Rotation send measure zero set to measure zero

Tags: lebesgue-measure

$m_2$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$. Suppose U is a zero set. $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is a rotation. Show $T(U)$ is a zero set. What I tried is to show the outer measure defined by open rectangle cover is equivalent to the outer measure defined by closed ball cover and closed ball is invariant under rotation, but it seems rather hard to show the equivalence.

Comment: If $R$ is a rectangle, can you show that $m (TR) = |\det T
| m(R)$?

Comment: Normally in this context, you would have proven that for any linear transformation,
$$
m(T(U)) = |\det T|m(U)
$$
Given this formula, the proof is immediate.

Comment: In fact, this exercise wants to show Lebesgue measure is invariant under all rigid motion before $m(T(U))=|detT|m(U)$

Comment: rotations are isometric operations, that is preserve the volume (Lebesgue measure) of the object being rotated. Same holds for translations. One can see a rotation also as a change of coordinates, so this would also imply measure-preservance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long winded  answer that doesn't use the usual $\det$ formula.

This shows that $m(TA) = m(A)$ for all measurable sets $A$.

Let $R_n = \{ [x, x+{1 \over 2^n}) \times [y, y+{1 \over 2^n}) | x,y \in {1 \over 2^n} \mathbb{Z} \}$. It should be clear that $R_n$ forms a partition of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It should also be clear that if $m>n$ and $S_n \in R_n, S_m \in R_m$, then either $S_m \subset S_n$ or $S_m \cap S_n = \emptyset$.

We see that $[0,1)^2$ can be written as the disjoint union of $(2^n)^2$ elements of $R_n$, each of which are translations of each other.

Define $\tau(A) = m(TA)$. It is easy to check that $\tau$ is a translation invariant measure since $m$ is.

Let $c=\tau([0,1)^2)$. From above, we see that if $S \in R_n$, then $\tau(S) = {1 \over (2^n)^2 } c = c m(S)$.

Since $T$ is invertible, we 
see that $U$ is open **iff** $TU$ is open.

Suppose $U$ is open. We want to show that $U$ can be written as a countable
disjoint
collection of elements of the $R_n$. Let ${\cal V}_1 = \{ S \in R_1 | S \subset U  \}$, $W_1= \cup_{S \in {\cal V}_1} S$,
${\cal V}_{n+1} = \{ S \in R_{n+1} | S \subset U \setminus W_n\}$, $W_n = \cup_{S \in {\cal V}_1 \cup \cdots \cup {\cal V_n}} S$. Let
${\cal V}$ be the countable pairwise disjoint collection ${\cal V} = \cup_n {\cal V_n}$.
We see that $U = \cup_{S \in {\cal V}} S$.

Then we have $m (TU) = \tau(U) = \sum_{S \in {\cal V}} \tau(S) = c \sum_{S \in {\cal V}} m(S)  = c m(U)$. (Note that this implies
$m(U) = c m(T^{-1} U)$.)

For any measurable set $A$, we have $m(A) = \inf \{ m(U) | U \text{ open}, A \subset U \}$, so there exists open $U_k$ such that $A \subset U_k$ and
$m(U_k) \to m(A)$. Then $TA \subset T U_k$ and so
$m(TA) \le c m(A)$. Similarly, suppose $TA \subset V_k$ and $m(V_k) \to m(TA)$,
then $A \subset T^{-1} V_k$ and so
$m(A) \le  {1 \over c} m(TA)$.

Hence $m(TA) = c m(A)$ for all measurable $A$.

Finally, since $T$ is a rotation, we have $m(T B(0,1)) = m(B(0,1))$, so $c=1$.